# bash: local: `0': not a valid identifier

Tags: bash

When I call for example encrypt HI the result is:

```
bash: local: `0': not a valid identifier
bash: local: `1': not a valid identifier
```

Here is the code:

```
#!/bin/bash
encrypt(){
    local s="$1";
    local lenght=${#s};
    local i=0
    while [ $i -lt $lenght ]
    do
        local j=1
        local letter=expr substr $s $i $j;
        letterToNumber $letter;
        echo $number;
        i=$[$i+$j];
    done
}
```

Comment: What's in  your `letterToNumber` function?
Btw, `lenght` is, I believe, the world's most common programmer typo :)

Comment: The `$[...]` is obsolete `bash` syntax with the same meaning as the POSIX standard `$((...))`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
 > local letter=expr substr $s $i $j;
```

Looks like this is your problem.  This is a newbie mistake where apparently you meant to write

```
local letter=$(expr substr "$s" "$i" "$j")
```

Newcomers sometimes seem to have a hard time with shell syntax.  The shell simply tokenizes your command from the left; the first token which does not contain `=` is a keyword or a command, and (in the general case) the rest of the tokens are just text to pass as arguments to that command.  So `letter=expr substr` will assign the value `expr` to the variable `letter` and (try to) run the command `substr`; and `local foo=bar baz quux` will declare the variables `foo`, `baz`,  and `quux` as local, and assign the value `bar` to `foo` while we are at it.

Using `expr` is very rarely what you want to do in a modern shell script.  Bash has a built-in substring operator; `${s:$i-1:$j}`

```
encrypt () {
    for((i=0; i<${#1}; ++i)); do
        letterToNumber "${1:i:1}"
    done
}
```

(I am guessing you also meant to say `number=$(letterToNumber "${1:i:1}"); echo "$number"` but that's just a [useless use of `echo`](http://www.iki.fi/era/unix/award.html#echo).)

Answer (score 1):

tripleee is right.

And though I do not have your letterToNumber func/program, I think there's 2 other problems:

```
#!/bin/bash
#set -v # always handy
#set -e # handy too

encrypt(){
    local s="$1";
    local lenght=${#s};
    local i=1 # <--------  start at 1, not 0
    while [ $i -le $lenght ] # <-------- le, not lt
    do
        local j=1
        local letter=$(expr substr $s $i $j);
        echo letter $letter
        #letterToNumber $letter;
        echo $number;
        i=$[$i+$j];
    done
}

encrypt HELLO
```

Output:

```
$ ./foobar.sh 
letter H

letter E

letter L

letter L

letter O
```

Comment: Don't stop there. The loop is much better expressed as a `for` loop.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `local letter=expr substr $s $i $j;`, which is incorrect (to know why, see answer by tripleee), you could do:

```
# Insert this line before `local s="$1";` or anywhere else before while loop    
local letter

# Inside the "while loop"...
letter=${s:$i:$j}
```

To calculate i=i+j, its better to use shorter (than yourth) BASH internal math syntax:

```
# Replace `local i=0` with this line:
local -i i=0 j=1
# i=i+j . Note: you dont need "$" here!
i+=j
```

Finally overall encrypt function code will be:

```
encrypt () {
            local s="$1" letter length=${#s}
            local -i i=0 j=1
            for ((; i<length; i+=j )); do
                    letter=${s:$i:$j}
                    letterToNumber "$letter"
                    echo $number
            done
            return 0
}
```

This code may be replaced by the simplest one-liner, but... you dont answer  (yet) about how to do that :)